# Run Python script at startup in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a short Python script that needs to run at startup - Ubuntu 13.10. I have tried everything I can think of but can't get it to run. The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
with open("/home/username/Desktop/startup.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(time.time()) + " It worked!")
```

(The actual script is a bit different, as I'm just using this for testing purposes, but you get the idea.)

I've tried all of the following, with no luck:

- Put the command `python startuptest.py` in `crontab`, as `@reboot
  python /home/username/Documents/startuptest.py`, both as the regular user and as `sudo`
- Put the command `python /home/username/Documents/startuptest.py` in `/etc/rc.local`
- Opened Ubuntu's Startup Applications and put the command there
- Done all of the preceding, putting the command into a shell script
  and calling that shell script instead

Nothing works. I get the feeling I'm missing something simple. Any ideas? (The script runs fine if I just run the command from a terminal.)

Comment: On /etc/rc.local, did you try to give the full python path there? And add a simple '/usr/bin/date >> /tmp/date.stamp' to rc.local for checking if the script is run.

Comment: Can you verify rc.local has +x privileges? What happens if you just try and run /etc/rc.local after startup with the Python script included?

Comment: with `crontab` you don't get your environment setup so it probably can't find `python` try qualifying `python` using the whole path `/usr/bin/python` or similar

Comment: rc.local has +x privileges; if I run it after startup the scripts runs. Still no dice on startup, though.

Comment: Robert - using /usr/bin/python in crontab seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831433/django-server-autorun-when-ubuntu-startup-or-reboot

Answer (score 58):

### Instructions

- Copy the python file to /bin:

  `sudo cp -i /path/to/your_script.py /bin`
- Add A New Cron Job:

  `sudo crontab -e`

  Scroll to the bottom and add the following line (after all the `#'s`):

  `@reboot python /bin/your_script.py &`

  The “&” at the end of the line means the command is run in the background and it won’t stop the system booting up.
- Test it:

  `sudo reboot`

### Practical example:

- Add this file to your Desktop: **test_code.py** (run it to check that it works for you)

  ```
  from os.path import expanduser
  import datetime

  file = open(expanduser("~") + '/Desktop/HERE.txt', 'w')
  file.write("It worked!\n" + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
  file.close()
  ```
- Run the following commands:

  `sudo cp -i ~/Desktop/test_code.py /bin`

  `sudo crontab -e`
- Add the following line and save it:

  `@reboot python /bin/test_code.py &`
- Now reboot your computer and you should find a new file on your Desktop: `HERE.txt`

Comment: Is `/bin` the only place where a python script can be run?

Comment: It needs to be in a directory where scripts run as root when the system starts. So for example inside `/boot` or `/etc` ... should also work.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/25805612/1964109 is simpler and more elegant. Using crontab feels so 2000.

Comment: @MaxN yeah, you are right. Anyway, crontab has some really nice features as, for example, you can make the script run at specific times.

Comment: When using `crontab -e`, the file gets saved in `/tmp` folder. Is that normal? Shouldn't such a file be saved in a more reliable folder like `/usr` or `/home` or `/etc` or `/opt`? Why is it stored in `/tmp`? It's not some temporary file that I'm creating. Couldn't it be saved in some other folder?

Comment: @Nav the file gets saved at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. The crontab file is not meant to be edited directly but through the crontab command using the `-e` option. Also if you don't use `sudo` to edit the crontab file, you will be editing the file for the current user, not the root user. This means that any commands added to the crontab file will only be executed as that user, not as the root user.

Answer (score 37):

Put this in `/etc/init`  (Use `/etc/systemd` in Ubuntu 15.x)

**mystartupscript.conf**

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

exec /path/to/script.py
```

By placing this conf file there you hook into ubuntu's [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) service that runs services on startup.

manual starting/stopping is done with
`sudo service mystartupscript start`
and
`sudo service mystartupscript stop`

Comment: mystartupscript.conf: unrecognized service

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO Ubuntu 15.x switched from /etc/init to /etc/systemd

Comment: it is really helpful ..bt stop is not working ....when i was doing ==>sudo service startpy stop ...it is giving me an error like this ===> stop: Unknown instance: ....
can u tell me what is the problem??

Comment: @SudipDas then it was not running. Either it completed ok on its own, or there is  an error in the startup script that prevents it from running. Logfiles are at `/var/log/upstart/[servicename]`. Or you can run the command after `exec` in a terminal to see what happens.

Comment: This solution is not working for me, but the one using crontab did work! I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I got this error: Failed to start mystartupscript.service: Unit notifyIP.service not found.

Comment: Error: Failed to start mystartupscript.service: Unit startup_peter.service not found

Answer (score 22):

If you are on Ubuntu you don't need to write any other code except your Python file's code , *Here are the Steps :-*

- Open Dash (The First Icon In Sidebar).
- Then type **Startup Applications** and open that app.
- Here Click the **Add Button** on the right.
- There fill in the details and in the command area browse for your **Python File** and click Ok.
- Test it by **Restarting System** . Done . Enjoy !!

Comment: by far the best method on ubuntu

Comment: What if the python script is running on virtualenv ? ie ; if you have to activate virutualenv before running the script  ?

Comment: In Lubuntu I had to add `python /path/to/script.py &` to the `Default Applications in LXSession`. The `&` is running the script in background. Check if running with `ps ax | grep python`.

Comment: although, if sudo is required, it might not work

Answer (score 13):

Create file ~/.config/autostart/MyScript.desktop
with

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=MyScript
Comment=MyScript
Icon=gnome-info
Exec=python /home/your_path/script.py
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=

X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=0
```

It helps me!

Comment: I tried this in Ubuntu it was working perfectly but I tried it in orange Pi it is not working. There was no ~/.config/autostart/ directory. I created first and did same as mentioned above but it did not work. Any solution

Comment: The "autostart" directory in .config does not exist on my ubuntu system. Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: @cheesus I wonder if `apt install gnome-tweaks` would create it for you? I'm also on 18.04 and I do have the folder which contains a couple `*.desktop` files which I know I added through the Tweaks GUI as startup applications

Comment: Similar end result as @Aditya Argawal's answer above, just via the CLI instead of GUI

Answer (score 2):

nano /etc/rc.local

and edit in

> python ~/path-to-script.py

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In similar situations, I've done well by putting something like the following into /etc/rc.local:

```
cd /path/to/my/script
./my_script.py &
cd -
echo `date +%Y-%b-%d_%H:%M:%S` > /tmp/ran_rc_local  # check that rc.local ran
```

This has worked on multiple versions of Fedora and on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, for both python and perl scripts.

Comment: I have tried the method here posted by jazcap53 as well as a version of the one here by RickyA and another one in which I modified the /etc/rc.local file.  My pyhton script works to create the HERE.txt file but in none of these cases does it make that file on reboot.