# Django Server autorun when Ubuntu startup or reboot?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, uwsgi

I want my logic server(Python3+Django+uwsgi+nginx) autorun when Ubuntu-server startup or reboot. So, I write a execute script (`uwsgi --ini=/data/xxx.ini`), and add it to `/etc/rc.local` .

Then, I restart server, logic-server running, **But** when program print log to file , python3 throw exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/handlers.py", line 73, in emit
    logging.FileHandler.emit(self, record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1041, in emit
    StreamHandler.emit(self, record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 984, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 915, in handleError
    traceback.print_stack(frame, file=sys.stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 286, in print_stack
    print_list(extract_stack(_get_stack(f), limit=limit), file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 30, in print_list
    print(item, file=file, end="")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 95-100: ordinal not in range(128)
Call stack:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "./carwashing/views/decorators.py", line 65, in _require_login_release
    json_resp = views(request, user=token_cache.employee, *args, **kwargs)
```

When I direct start uwsgi in manual, it works well.

Comment: You should use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

> You have to write a .sh file with virtual activate code

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
cd /path/to your/virtual environment  #path to your virtual environment
. bin/activate  #Activate your virtual environment
cd /path/to your/project directory
python manage.py runserver  #run django server
```

> then write a reboot cron job for this .sh file, it will work for you.
>
> Check this [link](http://pulse7.net/django/start-django-automatically-when-restart-system-server-in-linux/) for more details..