# How to code a shell script to run a program when the system login?

Tags: linux

I have write a python program that display the radio frequency, how to code a shell script to run it when the system login?

Comment: This might be better asked on a form about Linux not really related to programming as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see step by step on this link : 
https://embeddedday.com/projects/raspberry-pi/a-step-further/running-python-script-at-boot/

also here stackoverflow Link : [Run Python script at startup in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518522/run-python-script-at-startup-in-ubuntu)