# Auto startup my source code in ubuntu

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

My python source file automatically starts while I boot the system. I tried in `init.d` and some other shell scripts, but its not working. Note (I also make the executable file), but it doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of other posts covering this topic, notably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518522/run-python-script-at-startup-in-ubuntu)

> Put this in /etc/init (Use /etc/systemd in Ubuntu 15.x)
>   mystartupscript.conf
>   start on runlevel [2345] stop on runlevel [!2345] exec /path/to/script.py
>   By placing this conf file there you hook into ubuntu's upstart service that runs services on startup.
>   manual starting/stopping is done withsudo service mystartupscript start and sudo service mystartupscript stop

There is another solution [here also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) also