# How to run python script at startup

Tags: python, linux, centos

I'm trying to make a Python script run as a service.

It need to work and run automatically after a reboot.
I have tried to copy it inside the `init.d` folder, But without any luck.

Can anyone help?(if it demands a cronjob, i haven't configured one before, so i would be glad if you could write how to do it)

(Running Centos)

Comment: Did you add a shabang to it (`#!`)?

Comment: try putting the command in `/etc/rc.local`, make sure you use absolute path names, and don't forget to background the process with `&` if the process runs continuously

Comment: @Bitonator: afaik, this will not make the script a service.

Comment: Hi willem, Thanks for the answer. Well, where do i has the shabang? I need to write a bash script? I just cp that script to the init.d folder, did nothing else..

Comment: @bitonator, where i need to write the command?

Comment: At the end of the file, before `exit 0`

Comment: Which version of centos? They switched to a different init system (systemd) in version 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Python script at startup in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24518522/608639)

Answer (score 9):

run this command

```
crontab -e
```

and then add

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python /path/to/yourpythonscript
```

save and quit,then your python script will automatically run after you reboot

Answer (score 0):

There is no intrinsic reason why Python should be different from any other scripting language here.

Here is someone else using python in init.d: blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/07/… In fact, that deals with a lot that I don't deal with here, so I recommend just following that post.

Comment: Here is someone else using python in init.d: http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/07/getting-a-python-script-to-run-in-the-background-as-a-service-on-boot/  In fact, that deals with a lot that I don't deal with here, so I recommend just following that post.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Variant:-
open the /etc/rc.local file with:

```
nano /etc/rc.local
```

add the following line just before the exit 0 line:

```
start-stop-daemon -b -S -x python /root/python/test.py
```

or

Give absolute path of your command i.e

```
nohup /usr/bin/python2 /home/kamran/auto_run_py_script_1.py &
```

The start-stop-daemon command creates a daemon to handle the execution of our program. The -b switch causes the program to be executed in the background. The -S switch tells the daemon to start our program. And the -x switch tells the daemon that our program is an executable.

To check and Run

```
sudo sh /etc/rc.local
```