# How run a command (python file) on boot on AWS EC2 server

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having some problem making a python file run everytime the AWS server boots.

I am trying to run a python file to start a web server on Amazon Webservice EC2 server.

But I am limited to edit systemd folder and other folders such as init.d

Is there anything wrong?

Sorry I don't really understand EC2's OS, it seems a lot of methods are not working on it.

What I usually do via ssh to start my server is:

```
python hello.py
```

Can anyone tell me how to run this file automatically every time system reboots?

Comment: You don't say what problems/errors you are experiencing, but you might want to refer to `hello.py` via a full path name (eg `/users/home/ec2-user/hello.py`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your linux OS but you are on the right track (`init.d`). This is exactly where you'd want to run arbitrary shell scripts on start up.

Here is a great HOWTO and explanation:
https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html

and another stack overflow specific to running a python script:

[Run Python script at startup in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518522/run-python-script-at-startup-in-ubuntu)

if you want to share you linux OS I can be more specific.

EDIT: This may help, looks like they have some sort of launch wizard:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

> When you launch an instance in Amazon EC2, you have the option of
> passing user data to the instance that can be used to perform common
> automated configuration tasks and even run scripts after the instance
> starts. You can pass two types of user data to Amazon EC2: shell
> scripts and cloud-init directives. You can also pass this data into
> the launch wizard as plain text, as a file (this is useful for
> launching instances using the command line tools), or as
> base64-encoded text (for API calls).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am using windows powershell to access amazon web server via ssh. So the system should be AMAZON EC2 linux system. I searched a lot of methods but they all failed for access permission reasons

Comment: Thanks. Amazon EC2 instances are some standard linux distro, im just not sure which one. (or if you can choose) . Try some of these:
https://www.howtogeek.com/206240/how-to-tell-what-distro-and-version-of-linux-you-are-running/

And if you get permissions issues try running sudo before the command:
sudo <mycomman>

this will prompt you for password to run as a super user. This may be your SSH credential as well but i doubt it. You could check amazons documentation, that might help answer these questions.

Comment: Oh man, they dont indicate on my cursory search:
https://aws.amazon.com/mp/linux/

Documentation may be the key.