# How to restart a running python script if the Ubuntu 16.04 server crashes automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, server, ubuntu-16.04

I have a simple script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

i=0

while (True):
    print(i)
    i=i+1
```

I want this script to run in background 
If the server crashes, I want it to automatically restart an pick where the program left of
How do I do that

Comment: [You may look into this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25805871/12132322) This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have tu run your script as a service:
The file must have `.service` extension under `/lib/systemd/system/` directory.

Now Your system service has been added to your service. Let’s reload the systemctl daemon to read new file. You need to reload this deamon each time after making any changes in in .service file.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now enable the service to start on system boot, also start the service using the following commands.

```
sudo systemctl enable dummy.service
sudo systemctl start dummy.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to handle processes. To make your script start where it left off you need some kind of persistence, like a file or a database where you can put the last state of your script and read at the restart.