# running a python script when i turn my pc on

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I created a python script to control the RGB of my keyboard and my mouse and i want it to start when i turn my computer on. I have 2 solutions but i don't know which is the best.

the first solution is to build my script and run the executable on startup
the second solution is to run directly the python script with python.

the first solution is a little bit annoying because is i want to change the code, i need to rebuild my script. and also when i tried to run the exe (created with pyinstaller), it didn't work (because of the dlls i think)

the second solution is better if i want to change the code later, but i don't know how it would react if i run another python script (i don't even know if it's possible to run 2 python instances at the same time.)

so if you have any idea on which solution to choose, how to build a script using dlls with pyinstaller or if i can run multiple python instances (maybe i can run multiple venvs), feel free th help me.

PS: I tried to be clear but as i didn't speak english very well i don't know if you understood my issue.

Comment: You can use task scheduler for windows

Comment: This question was answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-windows-starts

Comment: For linux: cronjob

Comment: While cronjob can be used on linux, I think that more appropriate thing is to use systemd in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Using windows : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/autorun-a-python-script-on-windows-startup/

Using Linux : follow this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518522/run-python-script-at-startup-in-ubuntu#:~:text=Put%20the%20command%20python%20startuptest,and%20put%20the%20command%20there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518522/run-python-script-at-startup-in-ubuntu#:%7E:text=Put%20the%20command%20python%20startuptest,and%20put%20the%20command%20there)