# Running python script on boot in terminal on linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, boot

I want to have a python script that will automatically run on boot of my linux machine. However, it is very important that I can see the terminal output since it uses computer vision and displays certain calculations. Is it possible for it to be displayed as if I just opened a terminal and ran the script manually? Thank you!

Comment: This is more of a Linux question than a programming question, and is probably better suited for [linux.se] SE or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). Though be sure to check their question guidelines before posting.

Comment: Perhaps this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518522/run-python-script-at-startup-in-ubuntu

Comment: @Brian Wanting to know how to run a program at boot is both a programming and an operating system question. It'd be on topic on Unix & Linux, but it's also on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

If your linux system uses Systemd then it has that functionality build-in. Just create a new *myapp*`.service` unit (see `man systemd.service`) which starts the application, enable it (so it runs on boot) and the output will go to the journal. (available with `journalctl -u myapp`)

If it is not just about output but also being able to have input available then just have the application start within a terminal session (the `screen` tool would be a good candidate). The systemd unit can start the screen session on-boot, and you can just attach to that terminal at some point in the future (gaining full control and seeing all the historical output).