# Auto start python GUI app in Ubuntu startup

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, user-interface, systemd

I have been written a python code by cv2 to select videocapture 0 and blur something appears in the video ouput then show the new output with img show in Ubuntu, it works fine by running the script manually but when I want to make it run automatically when ubuntu startup and I want to raise the audio that was coming from the videoCapture how can I do that.

I tried to run it using systemctl by creating file.service in /etc/systemd/system with this code

```
[Unit]

Description=hashcode



[Service]

Type=simple

ExecStart=/root/run.py

Restart=always

RestartSec=1s

User=root



[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it's not working

Comment: What is exactly your question? You want to raise audio or you want to run a Python file on system start-up? What do you mean by "not properly"?

Comment: @SadraSabouri I want both, I apologize, I am not good at English. I meant that the application did not appear at the start on startup. The video of the opencv did not appear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Python script at startup in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518522/run-python-script-at-startup-in-ubuntu)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634410/start-python-script-at-startup

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371186/how-to-start-my-own-script-at-the-end-of-boot

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1112197/linux-how-to-run-python-script-on-startup

Comment: this is sysadmin stuff, not programming. try https://superuser.com/ or any of the previously mentioned links.